# How to use / start Windows 3.11 with FreeDOS

Tags: windows-3.x, freedos

I can't start Windows 3.11 in FreeDOS due some protected mode issues:

- `win /s` (standard mode) => Can't start Windows in Standard Mode. Try to use the extended mode `win /3`
- `win /3` (extended mode for 386) => *Windows cannot run in Advanced Mode for 386 PC because of the Protected Mode software already installed. Exit the Protected Mode software and try again.*

What I have done so far: added `InDOSPolling=TRUE` to C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM.INI section `[386Enh]`.

Is there a way to start Windows 3.11 in FreeDOS?

**Update**

If I start FreeDOS in `Safe Mode` I'm able to start Windows but just in the standard mode. `win /3` returns *Unsupported DOS Version*.

Comment: While there is some Windows compatibility code in the FreeDOS kernel, I don’t think the 386 Enhanced Mode was ever made to work with it.

Comment: Also, <https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/620615>

Comment: Windows 3.11 is difficult to get running without real MS-DOS and the XMS/EMS memory managers that come with MS-DOS. Why do you think Windows 3.11 will run under FreeDOS and why do you want to try it? It may not be possible or feasible.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 3.11 extended mode for 386 doesn't run under FreeDOS. From their [wiki](http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/Windows):

> … *Windows standard-mode works on FreeDOS, but ‘386-mode Windows for Workgroups 3.11 does not.*

Comment: Is the OP running Windows 3.11 or Windows for Workgroups 3.11?  I recall them as different products.

Comment: They are different products, but it's Extended Mode for 386 that's causing the startup to fault, and that's a common feature to all Windows 3.1x

Comment: The wiki is outdated, [it is now possible to run enhanced-mode Windows on FreeDOS](https://danielectra.github.io/blog/windows-31-on-freedos) but it involves rebuilding the kernel.

Comment: @StephenKitt I modified the latest kernel revision to enable use of the `-DWIN31SUPPORT` flag with the gcc-ia16 build. The build so far is available in https://pushbx.org/ecm/test/20230805.2/kwin31.zip and I created a PR at https://github.com/FDOS/kernel/pull/110 You should also use https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/fdshare.zip

Comment: @ecm I also tried to compile it but I have an issue with libi86 (./build.sh libi86) for the gcc-ia16 toolchain: _bios_disk, bdos, _makefcb, _spawnv, _spawnvp, _spawnlp and _searchenv fail. any advices? is it maybe connected with the linux subsystem in windows? Thx

Comment: @leon22. I think those are just tests and may fail for various reasons. Report to https://codeberg.org/tkchia/libi86/issues if you want. To work around test failures I ran `(cd build-libi86 && make install)`